# Ghost theme image stretching issue

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm using ghost theme and and I am facing an issue when uploading images,
when I upload any image its taking original image size and then the image is stretching in smaller resolutions. is there any option to make 100% width height for the image when uploading the image or any other solution to stop image from stretching. ?

```html
<img src="--1--3.png" class="kg-image medium-zoom-image" alt="" width="900" height="462" />
```